# How to download a file from EC2 instance to Local Computer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

i have an instance of ec2.it have some files.i tried to download my file from ec2 instance to my local Ubuntu 13.10.i run this command

```
scp -i /home/ritesh/.ssh/id_rsa2 apps@XXX.20.24.XXX:/home/apps/dev/comp-eng/arena-client/build/arena-client-7.1.0.zip
```

and in output i am getting

usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

i am using correct format i think.why i am facing this error instead of downloading file ??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to specify your download location. If its the current directory, you can just add a `.`.

`scp -i /home/ritesh/.ssh/id_rsa2 apps@XXX.20.24.XXX:/home/apps/dev/comp-eng/arena-client/build/arena-client-7.1.0.zip .`

Comment: +1 for the dot emphasis/explanation, it's easy to overlook and was stumping me.

Answer (score 11):

I find a simple solution for importing a file from EC2 to local machie

```
cd ~/.ssh
scp -i mykey.pem ec2-user@ipadress.zone.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/path/file ~/Desktop/target
```

Downloading file to your local machine .....

Hope it will be helpfull to someone

Answer (score 6):

So there is common formula

```
scp -i <private key> <user>@<host>:<server file path> <local path to download file>
```

Example :

```
scp -i domain.pem ec2-user@ec2-51-171-173-159.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/drupal/web/sites/default/files/test.jpeg /Users/ramesh/Downloads
```

Below is explanation

1. private file - .pem file with location
2. user -  Your AWS user
3. host - Your AWS host URL
4. sever file path - Full file path from server
5. local path to download file - Local folder location where you want to
   store your downloaded file

You can go to you EC2 Instance select it -> Click on Actions -> Connect, you will get the details

Answer (score 0):

An alternative simple method:

Ec2 allows you to manually download a file.

Thus, if we zip the folder, it becomes a file.

Step 1.

```
zip -r zipfile.zip folder_name/
```

Step 2.
Right click file and download.

Answer (score -1):

For EC2 ubuntu 
go to your .pem file directory 
scp -i yourkey.pem ec2user@DNS_name:/home/ubuntu/foldername/filename ~/Desktop/localfolder